# How do I increase screen resolution in ubuntu 12.04? I want 1366x768

Tags: display, resolution

I get the following output when I run `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 304mm x 190mm
   1280x800       60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Please give me a suggestion how to get 1366x768.

Answer (score 4):

According to that output, your laptop's native resolution is 1280x800, not 1376x768. Which laptop is it? You can run `xrandr -s 1366x768`, but it likely won't work, given your hardware seems to report it doesn't support that resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one screen connected: `LVDS1`, which supports these resolutions:

```
   1280x800       60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9
```

The `*` marks the current resolution, the `+` the preferred one by this screen.

Since 1366x768 isn't in the list, I'm afraid you can't set that specific resolution for this connected screen.

A possibility could be to scale the output resolution down to your monitors resolution. I tried this and it only worked on some systems. Additionally, there's an unresolved bug regarding a restriction of the mouse movement.

For example:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1280x800 --scale 1.2x1.2
```

This will give you 1.2 times your native resolution, but the screen output gets downscaled, so the output will look worse than at native resolution.

You could try to force another resolution, but **be warned**, some monitors could be damaged by this:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768
```

More info: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution/)

Comment: jitesh@jitesh-Compaq-Presario-CQ40-Notebook-PC:~$ xrandr -s 1366x768
Size 1366x768 not found in available modes
jitesh@jitesh-Compaq-Presario-CQ40-Notebook-PC:~$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1366x768
xrandr: cannot find mode 1366x768
jitesh@jitesh-Compaq-Presario-CQ40-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: My Laptop is Compaq-Presario-CQ40 14" Screen

Comment: There's usually no good reason to not use your screens native resolution. The output quality is much worse if you don't use it. Besides, there's not that much different in pixel count for 1366*768 = 1 049 088 and 1280*800 1 024 000. But you could try downscaling - I've added info for that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do panning on small laptop screens instead of scaling down

> xrandr --fb 1600x1200 --output LVDS1 --panning 1600x1200

Comment: Are there any advantages to it?

Answer (score -1):

To work with an old CRT monitor,
add the following to your xorg.conf:

before:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Option  "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection
```

after:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Option  "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "True"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1024x768 +0+0; 800x600 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 110.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 150.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

and get a stable flicker free workable screen.

Comment: His monitor is probably not a CRT, according to his xrandr output. (LVDS1 is his laptop screen, laptops with CRTs are quite extinct.)