# Installed NVidia 610 now, no menu on left

Tags: unity, nvidia

I'd like to use MythTV so I purchased an NVidia 610 and installed in my Ubuntu Server tower.  First boot, no issues, so I update Linux while installing NVidia drivers from "Additional Drivers".

After restart, the resolution was reduced. Once I log in and startx I see nothing but the blank desktop (resolution is correct).  No menu on left side.  I can right click or use power button to shut down.  What happened???

Comment: Install the accelerated Nvidia driver: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`

Comment: ... "already the newest version"

Comment: So try with reinstalling: `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`

Comment: tried your latest, same result.  desktop but no top or left side menus.

Comment: did you try to increase the resolution of the screen? folow this answer: http://askubuntu.com/q/189922/301039

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems the unity plugin was needed.

Answer (score 0):

While trying your suggestions I viewed this page: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

That solved the issue.  I started to step backwards, because the launcher DID show on first boot with the new card installed.  It was after I installed the NVidia drivers that I lost my launcher/title bar.

I removed the discrete card and was able to check "ubuntu unity plugin".  Rebooted with card re-installed and the plugin must have fixed it.