# how to increase the native screen resoltuion

Tags: resolution

I am looking for a way to increase the display resolution of my ubuntu desktop to a minimum of 4096x4096. I searched on the web but couldn't find a solution to this. Is there a way to make native resoltuion higher? I would be glad if you can share it with me or direct me in the right way to achieve this myself.
Thanks.

Comment: This could help you `http://askubuntu.com/questions/189922/how-do-i-increase-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-12-04-i-want-1366x768`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xrandr, though I recommend that you do not set your resolution to something higher than what your monitor can handle.

`xrandr` with no arguments returns information about your current displays:

```
mgodby@mg-ws1:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 306mm
   1600x1200      60.0*+
   1400x1050      74.9     59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-0 connected 1600x1200+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 306mm
   1600x1200      60.0*+
   1400x1050      74.9     59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
mgodby@mg-ws1:~$
```

You can set your resolution like so (replace `DVI-0` with your display name and `1400x1050` with your desired resolution):

```
xrandr -d DVI-0 -fb 1400x1050
```

A simple `man xrandr` will give you more information, and online searching will get you even more information yet.